# What is the difference between "Cloud Datastore indexes" and "Cloud Firestore indexes"?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

I'm reading the documentation of GCP documentation [*Choosing between Native Mode and Datastore Mode*](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore).

It explains the difference of Firestore in Native Mode (*Native*) and Firestore Data in Datastore Mode (*Datastore Mode*).

My question is about the following quotation:

> The project will use Cloud Datastore indexes instead of Cloud Firestore indexes.

The document above does not offer any explanation about the difference of the two index-types.

Could you explain me about the difference, or suggest any documentation useful?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indexes are managed differently and in non-compatible ways.

- Datastore mode: managed with an [index.yaml file and gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/indexconfig)
- Native mode: managed in the console, with SDK error links, or with the Firebase CLI, [see docs](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/indexing)

You cannot, for example, take a Datastore mode index.yaml file and use it to create Native mode indexes.